# What is the chemical reaction behind ginger milk curd?

Tags: proteins, enzymes

Pouring hot milk into ginger juice solidifies the milk. All I know is that ginger juice contains [Zingibain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zingibain) that could break down milk proteins into smaller polypeptides. I'm confused as though why is this sufficient to solidify the milk?

Comment: [Here's a whole pdf on the exact same thing](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.foodsciencejournal.com/download/364/3-3-29-466.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwif6ZPurJDuAhWPWX0KHR9LA4YQFjABegQIAhAF&usg=AOvVaw3ieN38bCJHEwQCYgSSKVk0)

Comment: [also here's more information from cooking stack exchange](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/30058/why-does-milk-curdle-after-being-boiled-with-ginger)

Comment: @Desai Sorry the pdf link isn't working for me. The cooking stackexchange only says that it will curdle, but I'd like to know what's happening at the molecular level?

Comment: [Ginger Milk Google Drive Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IgnirwbdulDVp8Xs4HRHGrlIrNB1COYF/view?usp=drivesdk)